# How to create an EntityManager instance in order to retrieve objects?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Note: I don't want to create services. It's just a simple application. In flat php this would be a piece of cake, but for some reason it's inordinately difficult in symfony/doctrine... :( The EntityManager is available in controllers, but for some reason it's not available in other classes. I don't care about MVP and clean code and all that. I just want it to work. I don't understand why it has to be such a pain in the butt.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $current_year=getdate()['year'];
    $em = new \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
    $approving_teachers = $em->createQuery('select u from Teacher t where IsAuthorized = 1')->getResult();

    $builder
        ->add('startDatetime', 'datetime', array('years' => range($current_year-1, $current_year), 'time_widget' => 'text'))
        ->add('hoursServed', 'number', array('constraints'=> array(new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Range(array('min'=>0, 'max'=>500)))))
        ->add('activity')
        ->add('student')
        ->add('approvingTeacher', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Teacher',
            'choices' => $approving_teachers
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at the doctrine config docs:  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#obtaining-an-entitymanager.  As you will see, it's a bit more involved than just newing the em.  Furthermore, the same em needs to be used throughout your code.  Hence the need for services.  Perhaps you could provide some details on why you don't want to inject it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an 'entity field type': http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html?

With entity field type you can use EntityRepository to retrieve anything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add `query_builder` to your `approvingTeacher` field. And use EntityRepository.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
```

...

```
    ->add('approvingTeacher', 'entity', array(
            ...
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return something...
            }
))
```

> Also, check the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Comment: Yes his query needs work but from the title he is asking how to instantiate an entity manager.

Comment: Yeah I know Cerad. I'm just giving him other option. I don't know other way than making it a service. But he can try my answer instead since he doesn't like it to be _"complicated"_